# Changing a passenger on a Lufthansa flight

Tags: air-travel, cancellations, bulgaria, lufthansa

I was originally planning to travel to Sofia this July with a friend of mine and booked round-trip flights with Lufthansa accordingly. Long story short, she will not be able to fly with me to Bulgaria, so my new plan would be to take the trip with a good friend instead.

Is it possible to change one of the passengers on the ticket from one person to the other? No other flight details need to be changed (i.e. seating, flight dates).

Some additional information. All 3 persons involved are German citizens. The flights in question are LH 1702 and LH 1705.

Note to any of the editors/admins: I put the cancellations tag because I was unable to find a tag that better approximated my need of changing flight details. If there is such a tag please change the tag or create such a tag.

Comment: Have you tried calling the airline?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[It is generally not possible](https://www.lufthansa.com/online/portal/lh/de/local?nodeid=2654840&l=en) to change the name on a Lufthansa ticket.

If your old ticket can be cancelled (this depends on the conditions of your fare class), the only option is likely to cancel the old ticket and buy a new ticket.

Comment: and that is not airline specific. You simply cannot transfer a ticket to another person.

Comment: @Aganju It is not uncommon for an airline to allow name changes on already issued tickets. Also in this case depending on the fare class, the name change may be associated with a fee.